# Is it possible for an argv[n] argument to have a length of 0?

Tags: c

I am checking the length of an argv argument, and am wondering if I also need to check it for 0?

Prove your answer by quoting the Standard, POSIX, or some other relevant source.

Comment: Command line parsing won't generate an argument of zero length. But you can easily generate an argument of zero length using the `exec` family of functions. So yes, your code should do any and all checks needed to verify that the strings in `argv` are valid.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jmQYVg3w

Comment: @user3386109: Command line parsing can generate an argument of zero length by starting from `program ""`

Comment: @Joshua Good point. I hadn't considered quoted arguments.

Comment: @pmg oh no. The invisible character is the ascii character with the id 0, which is called null. HOWEVER, the pointer is not null. So you need to check the value of the first character with argv[k][0]. This is not a good situation for me >:| EDIT: owait, is null the same as '\0' ? it might work ok then

Comment: @sneaker you should validate command line arguments just as you would do so with other user input. It's *not* a good situation, but handling the pesky user input can more difficult than the problem you are trying to solve. And it makes no difference if you are the user.

Comment: I think of it as: `NULL` is a pointer, `NUL` is the `'\0'` character (also "zero-terminator"). In many situations you can use plain old `0` for either `NULL` or `NUL` and the compiler will do the right thing after the proper conversion. `if (argv[argc] != NULL) /*system error*/;` same as `if (argv[argc] != 0) /*system error*/;` same as `if (argv[argc]) /*system error*/;`

Comment: `if (argv[0][0] == '\0') /*no program name*/;` same as `if (argv[0][0] == 0) /*no program name*/;` same as `if (!argv[0][0]) /*no program name*/;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It is possible `argv` to be NULL if `argc` is **zero**

> Is it possible for an argv[n] argument to have a length of 0

- `argv[0]` can have a zero length if program name is not provided by the environment. (***"argv[0][0] shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment"***)

C standard:

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1. The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this
>    function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
>    parameters: int main(void) { /* ... */ } or with two parameters
>    (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as
>    they are local to the function in which they are declared): int
>    main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ } or equivalent;9) or in some
>    other implementation-defined manner.
> 2. If they are declared, the
>    parameters to the main function shall obey the following constraints:
>
> - The value of argc shall be nonnegative.
> - argv[argc] shall be a null
>   pointer.
> - If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array
>   members argv[0] through argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers
>   to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host
>   environment prior to program startup. The intent is to supply to the
>   program information determined prior to program startup from elsewhere
>   in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
>   supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the
>   implementation shall ensure that the strings are received in
>   lowercase.
> - If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string
>   pointed to by argv[0] represents the program name; argv[0][0] shall be
>   the null character if the program name is not available from the host
>   environment. If the value of argc is greater than one, the strings
>   pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1] represent the program
>   parameters.
> - The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to
>   by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their
>   last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

Comment: I think the question is not whether `argv` can be NULL but whether `strlen(argv[n])` can be 0 for any `n` (assuming `argc >= n`).

Comment: @mkrieger1 amended to provide this too

Comment: "shall contain pointers to strings" - can this be considered the key part? 7.1.1 Definition of terms says: " A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.". These two clues together, in my interpretation could possibly be proof of the behaviour we empirically saw in @pmg 's example with submitting empty quotes as an argument and getting a valid string with only the null character in the first letter [0] position. If you agree with this, and add this info to the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @sneaker  it is implementation defined. Standard is silent about it. I am focusing on C language in general.

Answer (score -2):

> The arguments for `main` allow convenient command-line parsing of
> arguments. The types for `argc` and `argv` are defined by the language.
> The names `argc` and `argv` are traditional, but you can name them
> whatever you like.
>
> The argument definitions are as follows:
>
> `argc`
> An integer that contains the count of arguments that follow in
> *argv*. The *argc* parameter is always greater than or equal to 1.
>
> `argv`
> An array of null-terminated strings representing command-line
> arguments entered by the user of the program. By convention, `argv[0]`
> is the command with which the program is invoked. `argv[1]` is the first
> command-line argument. The last argument from the command line is
> `argv[argc - 1]`, and `argv[argc]` is always NULL.
>
> For information on how to suppress command-line processing, see
> Customize C++ command-line processing.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-170#standard-command-line-arguments)

You can check as

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1 && argv[1][0] == '\0') {
        // empty
    } else {
        // not empty
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that what you are quoting is for C++.

Comment: Your "source" is only an implementation by Microsoft and it is not a C standarizetion document